# How did Iaco Stark become a cyborg?

Tags: star-wars, comics

Yeah I never read Star Wars: Agent of the Empire Iron Eclipse, but I know that Iaco Stark became  a scary robot spider cyborg, but I would like to know the details because Wookieepedia hasnt updated the page yet.

Answer (score 1):

Stark was dying from some unnamed disease.

He had his son Iaclyn, who was an expert on droids, graft his head onto a droid body; and then simulated an industrial accident at the Iron Eclipse project to fake his death (his body - headless - was identified by his widow).

*Source:* Iron Eclipse Part 4.

[image]